# Crystal Reports parameter fields

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I am a new user of Crystal Reports 2008 and ECi M1 ERP.

1. An existing report within M1 prompts the user to select a [Product Group] and an [Inventory Class] plus other info (screenshot 1).
2. When I open the .rpt file within Crystal, I can see what appears to be the two relevant Parameter fields in field explorer (screenshot 2)
3. When I right click on one of the parameter fields, and select "Find in Formulas", the Formula Workshop opens but there are no matches for the parameter field (screenshot 3)

So my question is - how does the User selecting a [Product Group] / [Inventory Class] result in the report only showing that selection when the relevant parameter fields are not used anywhere?

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPkwx.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnmeN.png)

[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6eq1.png)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the ERP takes those choices and uses them to populate a temporary table, which is then used by the report.